# Add pagination is custom archives page on WordPress (Thesis Theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm using the following php code on a page to show 10 posts per page from a single category.

```
function my_page_of_posts5() {
    if (is_page('10')) {
        $custom_loop = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=10&cat=9');
        echo '<div class="my-archives"><ul class="archive-list">';
        if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : 
            while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();
                echo '<li><a class="archive-link" href="' 
                    . get_permalink() . '">' 
                    . get_the_title() 
                    . '</a> <span class="my-comment-count">( ';
                comments_number('0', '1', '%');
                echo ' )</span></li>';
                the_excerpt();
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
        endif;
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
add_action('thesis_hook_after_content','my_page_of_posts5');
```

I'm using Thesis WordPress Theme Framework.

I want to display pagination after these posts on the page.

What code shall I put there to show the pagination?

I've tried using the WP-Paginate plugin and putting the wp-paginate(); function on the page but it doesn't work fine.

Need another way to sort it out.

Comment: According to your bounty comment, is the plugin mandatory?

Comment: Not really, it's just that I'm assuming I'll need one of those plugins. A solution without the plugin will also be welcome.

Comment: I don't need a plugin either. Just need any pagination solution working on these pages.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what the exact behavior of your query is when you attempt to use `wp_paginate`, the best I can suggest is adding `'paged=' . get_query_var( 'paged' )` to your `WP_Query` args, comme ça:

```
$custom_loop = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=10&cat=9&paged=' . get_query_var( 'paged' ));
```

Once you add that, wp_paginate might work for you.

Give it a shot!

**UPDATE**

Ok, from the start:

1. declare and grab the `paged` query var
2. use it as an argument in your query
3. call `posts_nav_link` to get the necessary nav

Your whole snippet should work like so:

```
function my_page_of_posts5() {
    if (is_page('10')) {
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // what page? if none, one
        $custom_loop = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=10&cat=9&paged=' . $paged);
        echo '<div class="my-archives"><ul class="archive-list">';
        if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();
            echo '<li><a class="archive-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a> <span class="my-comment-count">( ';
            comments_number('0', '1', '%');
            echo ' )</span></li>';
            the_excerpt();
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
        endif;
    echo '</ul></div>';
    posts_nav_link(); // your next and previous links
    }
}
add_action('thesis_hook_after_content','my_page_of_posts5');
```

Comment: Not working for me. See, I followed this tutorial for the posts on a page: http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/add-category-posts-on-a-page/

Comment: Are you including `posts_nav_link`? You can paginate query results all you want, but if you don't have any way to get to them, it's no good!

Comment: I reckon that would work fine. But where do I put wp_paginate() function?

Comment: You'd have to replace `posts_nav_link` with `wp_paginate`, I suppose.

Comment: Still not working. Not sure why the `wp_paginate();` function isn't even displaying the pagination. :/

Comment: Why don't you try the standard issue Wordpress nav link functions first and eliminate the possibility that it's a plugin issue.

Comment: I'm trying `posts_nav_link();` now and it's still not working. As you can see on this page here: http://recruitmentjobs.co.uk/people-moves/

Comment: Did you check out the page mate? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Well, http://recruitmentjobs.co.uk/people-moves/page/2/ seems to work, so you must be nearly there. You might need to kill the `wp_reset_query();` line, as that might be stripping the info the pagination links need. Try that!

Comment: Well, removing `wp_reset_query();` didn't change anything but pagination was displayed when I used `<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
    wp_paginate();
} ?>` in thesis_after_content_box hook (using OpenHooks).

Comment: Aahh! But even that isn't working fine for it. Check out the pagination here: http://recruitmentjobs.co.uk/people-moves/ I can't go back to page 1 using that.

Comment: It looks like the wp_paginate plugin is defining the `current` page value incorrectly, likely because it is reading the `$paged` query_var of the wrong loop. So you've probably put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code instead, replace it what you have now.
It adds a pagination function I always use, no need for an extra plugin. Easy to customize.

```
<?php
function my_page_of_posts5() {
    if (is_page('10')) {
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // what page? if none, one
        $custom_loop = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=10&cat=9&paged=' . $paged);
        echo '<div class="my-archives"><ul class="archive-list">';
        if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();
            echo '<li><a class="archive-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a> <span class="my-comment-count">( ';
            comments_number('0', '1', '%');
            echo ' )</span></li>';
            the_excerpt();
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
        endif;
    echo '</ul></div>';
    theme_pagination();
    }
}
add_action('thesis_hook_after_content','my_page_of_posts5');

// based on http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin
function theme_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;

    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    if($pages == '') {
        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages) {
            $pages = 1;
        }
    }

    if(1 != $pages) {
        echo '<div class="pagination">';
        //if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages)
            echo '<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($paged - 1).'" class="previous" >';
            echo _x('previous', 'paginate', THEME_L10n);
            echo '<span>previouw-arrow</span></a>';

        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                if ($paged == $i){
                    echo '<span class="current number">'.$i.'</span>';
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'" class="inactive number" >'.$i.'</a>';
                }
            }
        }

        //if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages)
        echo '<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($paged + 1).'" class="next" ><span>next-arrow</span>';
        echo _x('next', 'paginate', THEME_L10n);
        echo '</a>';
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: is your code and situation the same as the code in the question?

Comment: It isn't working for me either. Nothing's changed after using your code. It works similar to the default code I've pasted in this question. Thanks for a try anyway :)

Comment: Have you put a `die()` in the filter to test that the function is actually executed?

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding this pagination code at the end of the code in your example:

```
//Set Blog Reading Settings to 10!
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array( 'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                            'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
                            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                            'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                            'end_size'=> 1,
                            'mid_size'=> 5 ) );
```

The code works in archive and category pages of normal free themes, but the one you are using is not free and is not open source, so it's hard to predict the result.

I think the posts quantity should be removed:

```
WP_Query('posts_per_page=10&cat=9')
// Just leave it like this:
WP_Query('cat=9')
```

The reason is the number of posts per page in WP is configured in the Reading Settings. Placing a quantity in the query might be blocking the pagination. Needless to say, there must be more than 10 posts for pagination to work.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi mate, this isn't working either. This situation is now being a pain but thanks for a try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a Two possible Solutions :**

(i). ***Solution #1 :***

i wish you will think that [wp-pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) is the best solution here. And it is too easy to integrate it in Thesis theme. As a Thesis theme user you are using thesis [openhook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thesis-openhook/) plugin already.

Now just follow the steps to add **pagenavi** in Thesis theme.

- Open **Apperance** > **Thesis Openhook**.
- Find **After Content**.
- Just paste the code in the box. `<?php cr_pagenavi(); ?>`
- Check **Execute PHP on this hook** and click save.

(ii). ***Solution #2 :***

**1.** First of all I installed a plugin which is [Simple Pagination](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-pagination/) (and its literally simple to use). If you’re using thesis, copy and paste this code in thesis_hook_after_content and hit save.

```
<div class="pagination">
<?php wp_simple_pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

**2.** Go to your custom_functions.php and paste this code to remove the Previous and Next post

```
function no_home_post_nav() {
if (is_home())
  remove_action('thesis_hook_after_content', 'thesis_post_navigation');
}
add_action('thesis_hook_before_content','no_home_post_nav');
```

**3.** Check out your new pagination on your homepage and customize it to any style you want.

Comment: Ok I tried both of them and this is what happened. Solution 1: This broke the rest of the page execution so nothing was appearing after the edited hook. Solution 2: You can see this live in action on http://recruitmentjobs.co.uk/people-moves/ as it's only displaying a div saying Pages and the pages aren't there. Thanks for a try anyway. It looks like this issue isn't resolving. :(

Comment: Any help on this please? It's been a while.